# Search a string in a certain column & use the string in column 1 in the same row

Tags: python, string, csv

I am trying to write a script for some pedigree analyses.

### Pedigree file

I have three tab-delimited columns (IndividualID, FatherID, motherID), like this (+- 200 lines):

```
AstorSjefVN   | SjefFtS      | LunaVN   
SjefFtS       | LarsCedaVdDD | MerelFtS  
LunaVN        | CasperVdH    | WinnieVtVB  
LarsCedaVdDD  | CecoVO       | AidaFtS  
MerelFtS      | NimkoVtN     | FamkeFtS  
CasperVdH     | SammyVdH     | DonnaVdH  
WinnieVtVB    | EllertVO     | MeejkeVdH  
CecoVO        | BoaikeVhK    | FokaVO  
AidaFtS       | GovertDK     | CindyVdSJ  
NimkoVtN      | DrepaVtB     | LetahVtOH  
FamkeFtS      | CaesarFtS    | FardiFtS
```

### Question

I want to search for a string in columns 2 and 3 (eg. `CaesarFtS`). If that string is present in one of those columns, I would next like to continue with the string in column 1 of the same row (`FamkeFtS` in this case), so I can again search for this new string in column 2 and 3 and so on. I want to use a while-loop for this, but I can't find how to search for a string in specific columns and continue working with the string in column 1 of the same row.
Researching, I found that using Pandas might be in place? I'm quite new to python, so I hope you can help me out!

Comment: *while-loop for this* - post your current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
end_of_tree = False
search_string = 'WinnieVtVB'

while not end_of_tree:
    with open('pedigree', 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile.readlines():
            if search_string in [x.rstrip() for x in line.split(' | ')[1:]]:
                print('%s match found in line: %s' % (search_string, line))
                search_string = line.split(' | ')[0]
                break
        else:
            print('No FatherID or MotherID found for: %s' % search_string)
            end_of_tree = True

>> WinnieVtVB match found in line: AlanTEST | CasperVdH | WinnieVtVB
>> AlanTEST match found in line: MerelFtS | NimkoVtN | AlanTEST
>> MerelFtS match found in line: SjefFtS | LarsCedaVdDD | MerelFtS
>> SjefFtS match found in line: AstorSjefVN | SjefFtS | LunaVN
>> No FatherID or MotherID found for: AstorSjefVN
```

Example input file used:

```
AstorSjefVN | SjefFtS | LunaVN
SjefFtS | LarsCedaVdDD | MerelFtS
AlanTEST | CasperVdH | WinnieVtVB
LarsCedaVdDD | CecoVO | AidaFtS
MerelFtS | NimkoVtN | AlanTEST
CasperVdH | SammyVdH | DonnaVdH
WinnieVtVB | EllertVO | MeejkeVdH
CecoVO | BoaikeVhK | MerelFtS
AidaFtS | GovertDK | CindyVdSJ
NimkoVtN | DrepaVtB | LetahVtOH
FamkeFtS | CaesarFtS | FardiFtS
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is indeed the while-loop I wanted to use. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I would point you in the direction of Regex string comparison.  As you continue to use Python or any language. Regex (regular expressions) allow for complex string searching and backwards lookup as you seem to be wanting to do here.

There a number of demos to learn Regex and here is my favorite site to [try out regex](https://regexr.com/) on a sample of data.

You might also use a python function that passes each line of your data into it and if your string matches then you can return the portion you want.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I'll check out the website!